# How to get select option text not value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Student Name: <span class="req-field">*</span>
  </label>
  <select ng-change="selectAction()" ng-model="formData.Name" ng-options="value.CompleStuId as value.Name for value in myOptions" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Please share your knowledge with me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sujeet, we will need a lot more than that. Maybe an example of what you tried on plunkr or jsfiddle...

Comment: Are you seeking for text not value or selected value ?

Comment: <select ng-change="selectAction()" ng-model="formData.Name" ng-options="value.CompleStuId as value.Name for value in myOptions" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required=""><option value="" class="">-- Select --</option><option value="0" label="Sibani Singh">Sibani Singh</option><option value="1" label="Chetna Bairagi">Chetna Bairagi</option><option value="2" label="Shikha Sharma">Shikha Sharma</option></select>

only student name i want to get

Comment: Exactly what JB said, you'll get your selected option's name in your model i.e. formData.name under your controller's scope

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `value.Name as value.Name for value in myOptions` if you want Name both as the label and the selected value.

`ngOptions`[<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage)

> for array data sources:
>
> ```
> select as label for value in array
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> ```
> value: local variable which will refer to each item in the array or each property value of object during iteration.
> label: The result of this expression will be the label for <option> element. The expression will most likely refer to the value variable (e.g. value.propertyName).
> select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent
> ```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.myOptions = [{CompleStuId: 1, Name: 'a'}, {CompleStuId: 2, Name: 'b'}, {CompleStuId: 3, Name: 'c'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Student Name: <span class="req-field">*</span>
  </label>
  <select ng-change="selectAction()" ng-model="formData.Name" ng-options="value.Name as value.Name for value in myOptions" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</div>
  
  {{ formData.Name }}

</div>
```

Comment: hi friends check out this code. I hope this sufficient for you all.
http://plnkr.co/edit/wPHc5HuXcTaU7qFkBlrO

Comment: You're plunker doesn't fill out your options. Can you put some example data in there? `ng-options="value.Name as value.Name for value in myOptions"`

Comment: i want to select value for get course name and joindate from database and  after click submit button save select student name.

Comment: Please consider posting another question asking about that problem. That seems outside of the scope of the original question posted. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips on asking questions on this site.